# How to make a plugin api route have permission?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, permissions

Hi I have a plugin for bookings installed. I would like to make WP headless so I'm using api calls of course,  and my plugin has api routes to call.

However, they are protected. :( 
How do I go about unprotecting them?

Route example is `http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wpamelia_api&call=/services`

When called in postman I get a 403 error.

Comment: 3rd-party plugins are off-topic here. You should ask the developers of the plugin.

Comment: I've just asked but they did send this before hand when I enquired about the api. I'm assuming its something to do with Wordpress: "We have API Routes for the Amelia app, but most of them are protected depends on of the permissions that is set in WordPress Accounts." @JacobPeattie